# How to convert lagarith lossless into some other formats?

Tags: windows-7, video-codecs

I have couple of large lagarith lossless media files which I want to convert into some other file formats that provide some compression. I wonder if there are any software that does that?

Comment: I've been searching for a tool that can convert from lagarith to something else. I'm using windows7

Answer (score 2):

Just about every video conversion software should be able to convert it, as long as the codec for it exists in the system. One good tool for it, that you can see what is going on, is "Virtual Dub". It might take a few minutes to an hour to get used to virtual dub, but it is well worth it.

Virtual dub wants to have "Video for windows" codecs.  "AVI synth" also can convert using it. and "Super" which uses mecoder and ffmpeg can use it. (beware super is now packaged with junkware stuff that you must avoid on installations)

Doom discussion http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-86148.html

Codec Site location http://lags.leetcode.net/codec.html

Virtual Dub Home http://virtualdub.sourceforge.net/

Squid codec page http://members.optusnet.com.au/squid_80/ (doesnt look like it is on it, but other important ones are)

http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html (super with BIG BEWARE of junkware disclaimer)

other notes: For 64bit programs they want 64bit codecs (or instalations at least that go in the right places for that designation) for 32bit programs you need 32bit codecs.